# How to perform COPY TO in PostgreSQL without reordering CSV file

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, copy

I have a CSV file with two columns, one populated(zipcodes), and one empty(rate). I have a postgreSQL table with a duplicate zipcode column and a rate column that is ~half filled with values and half null.

```
(file.csv)
zipcode,rate
11111,
22222,
55555,
33333,
44444,

(table)
id| zipcode| rate
----------------
1 | 11111  | 33.53
2 | 22222  | null
3 | 55555  | 31.20
4 | 33333  | 44.35
5 | 44444  | null
```

My problem is, when I try to merge the populated rate cells into the CSV file,

```
=# COPY (SELECT zipcode, rate FROM table) TO '/Users/User/path/file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

postgres reorders the cells of the CSV file and places rows that contain null values above the cells with values for rate, like so -

```
(file.csv)
zipcode,rate
22222,
44444,
11111,33.53
55555,31.20
33333,44.35
```

The blank cells for rate are desirable in my case, I just need a way to retain the row order of the original .csv file.

```
=# COPY table (zipcode, rate) TO '/Users/User/path/file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

gets the same result. Was wondering if an ORDER BY id in there somewhere might work, but no success yet. Using psql 10.3.

Comment: `COPY (SELECT zipcode, rate FROM table order by id) TO ...` should work fine. How are you using an ORDER BY when it doesn't work?

Comment: Oh thanks so much! Worked perfectly, I'd just been trying it in different places outside of the parenthesis. Rookie SQL mistake I guess..